# How to practically unchain yourself from sins?

Tags: sin

I made a promise to Allah and broke it. I know I have to fast 3 days to make this up.

Problem: I slept early, set alarm, but just couldn't wake up early enough to fast. I know why this is happening. The pious predecessors explained that one who is unable to fast or pray qiyam is chained by their sins. And this is absolutely true. I've been sinning alot lately and I'm absolutely worried.

Basically: How do I stop my habitual, perpetual sins? I make lists, I look at factors which lead to them, make tauba often, pray salah in the masjid but just keep repeating my sins. This means my repentance is not sincere. Example of sins which I keep repeating and are chaining me:
1) Disrespect to parents
2) Masturbation 3) not having khushoo in salah.

What are practical ways to STOP sin? I'm so frustrated. I've tried so many methods to change myself, practical , spiritual - NOTHING is working. I (rightfully so) feel like a worthless piece of flesh. It's by Allah's clemency and absolute mercy I'm alive.

Comment: As written, this looks like it will attract speculation and opinion rather than practical *answers*. Such questions do not work well under the Stack Exchange model: See http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not appropriate to feel worthless - Allah chose you by creating you, and moreso by blessing you with Islam. Meaning, He thinks you are capable of great things and great worship. If you think you're worth something, you'll put in the effort to change.

The way to do this is to kickstart the purification of your heart. Get a book on this, figure out what diseases ail it, and treat those diseases. Be brutal about cutting those things out of your life which contribute to your habits. Get a book on habit change and do what it takes to kick habits.

Start small if you can't start big. If you can't wake up for tahajjud or fasting, pray extra during the day. Memorize more Qur'an in the day. Learn (Qur'anic) Arabic if you don't already know it.

Finally, and this is perhaps the most practical tip: Sleep two hours earlier than you normally would. The root of so many things that seem unachievable is not sleeping early enough. It really is that simple.

Answer (score 0):

Brother, I too was facing such problems not long time ago but now I made up myself and I see myself coming out of it.

Simple, practical and effective thing to get out of your sins is try your best to apply whatever hadith you know of, obey the orders from Our lord and Prophet (peace be upon him), try to apply every sunnah in your life. Read Quran, understand the meaning and try to memorize it. Recollect the meaning when you recite in salah.

And to get up soon for Tahajjud and fasting, finish off your dinner before Isha salah and after salah go to bed. While on bed recite

1. Make intension that you will recite Surah Ikhlas 100 times
2. Recite Surah Al-Fatiah 3 times
3. Recite Surah Ikhlas 5 times
4. Say "As-tagh'fir-ul-lah" 10 times
5. Surah Ya'seen once.

Do all this after your Wu'zu (ablution) and make a simple Du'a to Allah to wake you morning. And tell the Angles on your shoulder to wake you up for Tahajjud.

In Shaa Allah you will become pious.

Do not forget "Allah has Honored All Children's of Adam A.S